# Why does Linq to DataTable stop working when I import an Excel library?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I made a Linq to DataTable and it worked, but I imported a library "Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel", and the linq stopped working.

How could I solve it?

I have imported the necessary libraries to use Linq but it still does not work.

```
'Library
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

'Linq
Dim filas = From fila In tabla.Rows
            Group By FechaFila = fila(2), Activi = fila(3), CodEquipo = fila(4), CCosto = fila(5), Inver = fila(6)
            Into Grupo = Group
            Where Grupo.Count > 1
            Select FechaFila, Activi, CodEquipo, CCosto, Inver, Contador = Grupo.Count()
```

It shows the following message:
Expression of type object is not queryable...

Comment: You probably have a name clash.  I've seen issues with importing the `Excel` namespace that way before.  I think that it is usually done by aliasing that namespace: `Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.  You then qualify any types in that namespace with `Excel` and all your existing code should still work.

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney, this works for me..

Comment: @jmcilhinney: Can you post that as answer, please? (Not that you need more reputation I guess, but it would not be unanswered anymore).

Comment: @Christoph, I didn't post it as an answer initially as I wasn't 100% sure it was the issue.  It seems that it was though, so I've done as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a name clash. I've seen issues with importing the Excel namespace that way before. I think that it is usually done by aliasing that namespace:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

You then qualify any types in that namespace with `Excel` and all your existing code should still work.